# How to disable video recording and screens Shots with Sauce Connect, Linux?

Tags: saucelabs

I'm wondering how I can use Sauce Connect and their rest api to disable disable video recording and screen shots. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know to disable video recording and screenshots is when you create a `WebDriver` instance with Selenium, you have to set the desired capabilities named `record-screenshots` and `record-video` to `"false"`. For instance, in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

desired_capabilities = dict(
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)

desired_capabilities["record-screenshots"] = "false"
desired_capabilities["record-video"] = "false"

driver = webdriver.Remote(
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities,
    command_executor="http://localhost:4444/wd/hub")
```

The REST API is meant to be used after a test has started so it would not be able to *prevent* the creation of the video and screenshots in the first place. I've seen no evidence that Sauce Connect would be able to do anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the Sauce Labs documentation (https://docs.saucelabs.com/reference/test-configuration/#disabling-video-recording) explaining how to disable the video recoding and screen captures. It's actually a desired capability that is passed as part of the test. Can you please provide more clarity on the Sauce Connect question.

Comment: I tried that already, but no luck, it still post processes everything sadly. I've sent an email to the saucelabs guys, hopefully they will have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean value as part of DesiredCapabilities to turn video recording on or off.

Suggest that it makes sense to only record video when the test fails, which is what [Saucery](http://github.com/Sauceforge/Saucery3) does.  It does work.  Have a look at [this](https://github.com/Sauceforge/Saucery3/blob/master/Saucery3/Capabilities/Base/BaseCapabilities.cs) class